# CloudKit Modify Existing CKSubscription

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

An existing CKSubscription that has been saved to publicDatabase cannot be modified directly, can it ?

Looking at class documentations, it can only be deleted, and a new CKSubscription with new behavior can then be created.

Is this correct ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct. Any CKSubscription object cannot be modified once created and saved to a public OR private database. You can only delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you were looking for...

"A `CKModifySubscriptionsOperation` object saves changes to one or more CKSubscription objects" ([from documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckmodifysubscriptionsoperation)).